# Create algebraic data type case class from a string

Tags: scala, enumeration, case-class, algebraic-data-types

Instead of using Scala `Enumeration`, I would like to represent my values with case classes as algebraic data type.

```
  sealed abstract class MeasureType
  case object Hour extends MeasureType
  case object Day extends MeasureType
  case object Week extends MeasureType
  case object Month extends MeasureType
```

I wonder, is it possible to create objects from a string, like with `Enumeration`:

```
MeasureType.withValue("Hour")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a singleton companion object `MeasureType` and write `withValue` method by hand using pattern matching on the argument.

```
object MeasureType {

    def withValue(val : String) : MeasureType = val match {
        case "Hour" => Hour
        case "Day" => Day
        case "Week" => Week
        case "Month" => Month
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("unrecognized name: " + val);
    } 
}
```